# Icon idea for the air line distance between two places?

Tags: icon, symbolism

The user is allowed to enter an address.
After that he is (next to other information) shown the direct airline distance to that place.

I just can't come up with an icon that fulfills following:

- this is not a routing distance
- this is the direct flying connection
- this has nothing to do with airplanes
- takes up very small space

Any ideas would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I'm sorry if this came off wrong. I really expected there to already be an icon for this, but I can't find one. Also I don't want to have anybody do my work for me. I'm just stuck, because I can't come up with something clever for this disambiguation.

Comment: I would think circle with a single parabolic path in a dotted line would do the trick. However, I'm voting to close because this is a brainstorming question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did your final solution look like?

Comment: Sadly the feature this is related to never made it into the product :( So the icon never made it past a place-holder. .. But for what it's worth: I really enjoyed the ideas, so thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you said that the icon does not have to utilize an airplane, but if we are talking about airline miles, I was thinking it might work anyway.  I found a few images that might spark the creativity genius in your quest for an icon composition.  Maybe try checking these out:

Shows a map and ruler:

[image]

Shows a map and GPS pin:

[image]

Hope some of those might help you out.  Good luck!

Comment: Shows a plane with a tail (indicating travel):
[link](http://www.colourbox.com/preview/6328342-867326-illustration-of-airplane-icon-take-off-showing-its-path-speeding-up-this-graphic-can-also-represent-silhouette-symbol-of-a-military-jet-zoom-in-the-sky-with-high-speed.jpg)

Shows a plane with a straight line tail (indicating a direct flight path/distance):
[link](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc/atc0804_At%20Anchor9.png)

Comment: Thanks, a ruler might do the trick, because you can only measure something straight with a ruler. But I'll wait a day or two until I'll mark yours as correct to not discourage others.

Answer (score 1):

With apologies for my rough sketches and webcam photo of said sketches:

[image: possible distance sketches]

Three of these are illustrating the same idea: Pins, markers, or dots representing points A and B, and something to connect them like a dotted line or an arrow.

If your audience is using the Latin alphabet and if "traveling from point A to point B" is a phrase used outside of English, you could do something with the letters.

Answer (score 0):

I associate the saying (UK) 'As the crow flies' to indicate a straight line distance between A and B. Maybe incorporate a crow in the icon??

Comment: I'm german and even though I have decent english skills I did not know that, so it probably won't work on an international basis. But thanks.

Comment: True. That saying is very British.